# Why I get a error 200 by websocket with python?

Tags: python, node.js, websocket

Code:

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const shaUtil = require('js-sha256');

String.prototype.hashCode = function() {
  return shaUtil(String(this));
};

const server = new WebSocket.Server({port:2909}); // Change to another port if you like.
// Hashes of client keys. Generate them using getHash.js and place them here.
const passes = {
    '86cec081a5288000ddb804c24ac70de62a5060e5b4f4068b01a01f9f29dddacc': 0, // Receiver's key.
    'c01223ad2ba8cdd184ded788cf6d3469111229cbe6cb3939ce24f471e8f257ca': 1, // Buzzer #1's key.
    '5476be1700a54be0572b0066b32b5905986641fa163c5eabd52369eb3a2685cf': 2 // Buzzer #2's key...
    
};
var receiver = null;
var senders = {1: null, 2: null, 3: null, 4: null}; // You can add more/remove buzzers if you want to.

const lockClients = true; // If it is true, a connected client will not be overriden by another client logging in until it disconnects.
if (lockClients) canConnect = function(id) {
    if (id == 0) return receiver === null;
    return senders[id] === null;
}
else canConnect = function(id) {
    return true;
}

function processBuzzer(client) {
    if (receiver == null) return;
    receiver.send('BUZZER '+client.buzzerId);
    //console.log('Buzzer #'+client.buzzerId+' is activated.');
}

function onDisconnect(id) {
    if (id === 0) {
        receiver = null;
        console.log('Receiver has disconnected.');
    } else {
        senders[id] = null;
        console.log('Sender #' + id + ' has disconnected.');
    }
}

server.on('connection', function(client) {
    client.sendBuzzer = function() {};
    client.on('message', function(message) {
        if (message.startsWith('PASSWORD: ')) {
            let id = passes[message.substring(10).hashCode()];
            if (id !== undefined && canConnect(id)) {
                if (client.buzzerId !== undefined) onDisconnect(client.buzzerId);
                client.buzzerId = id;
                if (id === 0) {
                    receiver = client;
                    console.log('Receiver has connected.');
                } else {
                    senders[id] = client;
                    console.log('Sender #' + id + ' has connected.');
                    client.sendBuzzer = function() { processBuzzer(this) };
                    client.send('CONNECTED SUCCESSFULLY');
                }
            }
        }
        if (message == 'BUZZER') client.sendBuzzer();
    });
    client.on('close', function() {
        if (client.buzzerId !== undefined) onDisconnect(client.buzzerId);
    });
});

console.log('Server is running.');
```

If i started this with nodeJS with "node server.js", it appears Server is running.....no mistakes.....and now, Iwill connect to this server with the receiver.py (Python-File):

```
serverAddress = 'ws://192.168.1.50:2909' # The server's address.
clientKey = 'receiver' # The client key corresponding to the receiver's hash.
buzzerSoundFile = 'buzzer.wav' # The name/path of the buzzer sound file.

import asyncio
import websockets
from win32com.client import Dispatch
import winsound
from threading import Thread

app = Dispatch('Powerpoint.Application')
def playBuzzerSound():
    global buzzerSoundFile
    winsound.PlaySound(buzzerSoundFile, winsound.SND_FILENAME+winsound.SND_ASYNC)

async def mainFunction():
    global serverAddress, clientKey
    async with websockets.connect(serverAddress) as ws:
        await ws.send('PASSWORD: ' + clientKey)
        while True:
            msg = await ws.recv()
            if msg.startswith('BUZZER '):
                if app.Run('onBuzzerActivated', int(msg[7:])):
                    Thread(target=playBuzzerSound).start();

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(mainFunction())
```

I got an error 200 like this:
websockets.exceptions.InvalidStatusCode: server rejected WebSocket connection: HTTP 200

What's wrong ??

Comment: In HTTP 200 is the opposite of an error. It means 'OK'.

Comment: Okay.....but my HTML-Site didn't connect?? Okay.....but my HTML-Site didn't connect ?Tthe whole error:
C:\Users\Steven\node_modules>python receiver.py
C:\Users\Steven\node_modules\receiver.py:40: DeprecationWarning: There is no current event loop
  asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(mainFunction())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Steven\node_modules\receiver.py", line 40, in <module>
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(mainFunction())
  File "C:\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 641, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()

Comment: File "C:\Users\Steven\node_modules\receiver.py", line 32, in mainFunction
    async with websockets.connect(serverAddress) as ws:
  File "C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\websockets\legacy\client.py", line 632, in __aenter__
    return await self
  File "C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\websockets\legacy\client.py", line 649, in __await_impl_timeout__
    return await asyncio.wait_for(self.__await_impl__(), self.open_timeout)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 447, in wait_for
    return fut.result()

Comment: File "C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\websockets\legacy\client.py", line 660, in __await_impl__
    await protocol.handshake(
  File "C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\websockets\legacy\client.py", line 327, in handshake
    raise InvalidStatusCode(status_code, response_headers)
websockets.exceptions.InvalidStatusCode: server rejected WebSocket connection: HTTP 200```

Comment: Are you able to connect via a browser?

Comment: For those confused about why a 200 status would be considered an error - in websockets, the initial handshake is done through http and a 101 (Switching Protocols) status is expected (not a 200). This means  that we switch from http to websockets after a successful handshake.